# Server restart issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

How can I restart a project I'm building to run on my vs code terminal, the app consist of react, mongodb, NodeJS and express. I have tried npm run, npm start but cant get me back on track to complete my project.

Comment: We need more than this. Maybe post your package.json file, do you get any errors when running npm start?

Comment: You will have to identify / search package.json file and see `scripts` section in package.json. Navigate to the root of folder has package.json in terminal and then execute `npm start` in terminal will start application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.